# How to convert separated Year(int), Month(int) and Day(int) columns into DateTime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Our ERP system holds year, month and day in separate int columns. I want to combine those 3 int columns into one DateTime, How can I convert it in the SQL Server.

```
Year | Month | Day
--------------------
2016 | 1     | 23
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx)(`SQL Server 2012+`):

```
SELECT DATEFROMPARTS([Year], [Month], [Day]) AS DateTim
FROM table_name
```

---

`SQL Server 2008` (assuming that year is 4-digit):

```
SELECT CAST(CAST([year]  AS VARCHAR(4)) + '-' + 
            CAST([month] AS VARCHAR(2)) + '-' + 
            CAST([day]   AS VARCHAR(2)) 
       AS DATE) AS DateTim
FROM table_name;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445223)**</kbd>

---

As *[Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)* proposed in comment to utilize `YYYYMMDD` as `INT` to convert to `DATE`:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST([year] * 10000 + [month]*100 + [day] AS VARCHAR(8)) 
           AS DATE) AS DateTim
FROM table_name;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445310)**</kbd>

## Addendum

To address *[ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/344949/ypercube%E1%B5%80%E1%B4%B9)* concerns about dateformat we could utilize [`ISO-8601`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) which is not affected by `DATEFORMAT` or `LANGUAGE` settings:

> yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss[.mmm]

```
 SELECT CAST(RIGHT('000'+ CAST([year]  AS VARCHAR(4)),4) + '-' + 
             RIGHT('0'  + CAST([month] AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + '-' + 
             RIGHT('0'  + CAST([day]   AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + 'T00:00:00' AS DATE)
 FROM table_name
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo3`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445389)**</kbd>

To handle years before 1000 should be padded with zeros.

Comment: @ayilmaz There is also `DATETIMEFROMPARTS` and more datetime functions :)

Comment: Unfortuantely, server is 2008. whatelse can I use? I will mark your answer as correct, by the way

Comment: I think a somewhat easier solution is `cast(cast(year * 10000 + month*100 + day as varchar(8)) as date)`, but it is the same idea.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yup, only two conversion instead of 4 :)

Comment: You could skip the `+ '-'`. `YYYYMMDD` format is fine for dates and datetimes. But you should take care that month and date are padded with 0 on the left.

Comment: try your query with some [weird parameters: `(6,1,12)`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/445299)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ There is no need to pad month or day. `SELECT CAST('2015-1-1' AS DATE)` will work. But you are right about year, if it is not 4digit it will fail.

Comment: Yes. And the `2015-3-7` may succeed but I'm not sure it's safe (will it be 7th of March or 3rd of July? It may depend on various config and settings.) My point was that `YYYYMMDD` is 100% safe when converting string to dates/datetimes.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Please check  **[demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/445359)** (first column vs second). It looks that `yyyy-mm-dd` is language independent where `dd-mm-yyyy` depends on lang

Comment: Yes, there are other settings, too. See Aaron Bertrand's blog: [Mishandling dates](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries). `YYYYMMDD` is 100% safe and `YYYY-MM-DD` is almost always safe. So, your queries may be correct or not, dpends on what the values of the `year` in OP's data are. If they have year before 1000, it may result in errors or wrong conversions.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I agree that `year` should be padded with `zeros` to handle years before 1000. But `ISO-8601` is 100% safe as is `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: Oh yes, if you add the `T00:00:00` after a char-10 string, yes. But if the month or date is single digit, your query will produce a format of `YYYY-M-DT00:00:00` which is is not ISO 8601 ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ Yup, be puritst to the end :) Anyway I highly doubt that any ERP system contains data from first millennium

Answer (score 1):

We can use SQL's CONVERT function to get Datetime value :

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Day) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), Month) + '/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), Year),103) FROM Table_Name
```